# Janus GridEX Problem

Tags: vb6

It's a longshot that anyone can help with this, but here goes.  I inherited a VB6 app with a Janus GridEX control.  It iterates through records, and is editable.  Problem is, if I edit a cell and hit the button to go to the next record, the change is applied to the next record, not the one I was editing.  It's like, I need it to finish up the edit before going to the next record.  I've had this sort of problem before in VC++, and sometimes you have to "KillFocus" on the control you're on or something.  I just don't know what to do here.  I tried sending a carriage return, since if you return out of the edit cell, it works, but sending a carriage return manually doesn't work.  What's the secret?

Answer (score 2):

Is your grid bound or unbound?

It's hard to tell from your description, but I imagine that if your are having this problem then it's probably bound.

As the other answer asked, is the button the RecordNavigator that is built into the control or is it a separate button? The reason I bring this up again, is that I have seen issues in the VB6 applications I support where a toolbar will often intercept and interfere with how the JanusGrid should work.

To get around this limitation, I have added the following code in the click handler of any toolbars where there is also a JanusGrid control on the form.

If `jsgxYourGridName.EditMode = jgexEditModeOn` Then `jsgxYourGridName.Update`

This way any changes are immediately applied to the current row.

If this does not help, then I have also seen problems where the recordset that is bound to the grid gets out of sync with the internal recordset in the grid. You can check this by comparing the bookmark of the grid to the bookmark of the recordset.

Ie. `mrsYourRecordset.Bookmark = jsgxYourGrid.ADORecordset.Bookmark`

At one point I may have also used something like this.

```
jsgxYourGrid.ADORecordset.Bookmark = jsgxYourGrid.RowBookmark(jsgxYourGrid.RowIndex(jsgxYourGrid.Row))
```

Finally you can try setting a breakpoint in the `BeforeUpdate`, `RowColChange` and/or `AfterColUpdate` events of the grid, to see what record the grid is really on when clicking on the button.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the button is internal to Janus GridEX or not. If it internal then just about the only thing you can do is look at the events the control exposes to see if there a sequence that can let you know that this problem occurs. Then you can try to take corrective action by restoring the row you moved to and put the edit in the row you left.

If the button is external to Janus then you can use the debug mode to trace sequence of statement that control the transfer of focus to the next row. It could be something out of order or a side effect of the particular sequence of commands. I have run into both with different controls.

Remember that you can edit while in debug mode so you can try different approaches and test until you find one that works.